# Usage of "anyone" and "anyone else"

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the following sentences?

1- He sang the song better than anyone else has ever done.

2- He sang the song better than anyone has ever done.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few contexts, such as...

> 1: *Does anyone [else] want a cup of tea?*
>    2: *I'd rather die myself than kill anyone [else]*

...where including ***else*** radically changes the implication. In the first it's certain at least *somebody* (probably the speaker) wants a cup of tea. The second would only be likely to be said by someone who had *already* killed at least once before.

---

But usually (as in OP's context) there's no real *semantic* effect (the meaning doesn't change). It's just that ***else*** adds a touch of ***emphasis*** (even more so if it's [*better than anyone else in the whole wide world*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22better%20than%20anyone%20else%20in%20the%20whole%20wide%20world%22)).

---

EDIT: I've just realised that my example re *touch of emphasis* above is potentially misleading. Including ***else*** doesn't actually imply anything like *...in the entire universe*. What it does is draw attention to the fact that no *alternatives* are better - which often implies *contextually-relevant* alternatives. Thus one workman might say to another *Why don't **you** ask the boss for a raise?*...

> 3: *... You know him better than anybody*
>    4: *... You know him better than anybody else*

It's a fine point, but I'd say the first version (which might even feature exaggerated stress on ***anybody***) can more easily carry *...in the world* as an intended (but unspoken) meaning, where the second more naturally implies *...in our workgroup.* That's to say, *we the workmen* are the contextually relevant group within which no-one else knows the boss better than the addressee (and it's quite possible none of us really know the boss very well, but *somebody* must know him at least a little better than anyone else in that group).

Comment: Thank you. So both are correct?

Comment: Just for the hell of it (because I *really* couldn't decide whether either might be more likely on average), I searched Google Books for both [*better than anyone has ever done*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22better+than+anyone+has+ever+done%22) AND [*better than anyone **else** has ever done*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22better+than+anyone+else+has+ever+done%22) (getting "guesstimates" of 420 and 426 hits respectively). After scrolling through half-a-done pages on each, the guesses sharpened to 410 against 409. I'm just amazed they're as finely-balanced as that!